# Send over MPI_Bcast an MPI_PACKED message

Tags: c, char, mpi, dynamic-arrays

I have a message that I want to send in broadcast by using MPI_Bcast.
I have two structs with, near the others, dynamic arrays, and because of that I decided to use MPI_Pack and MPI_Unpack.

Here below my solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define DEBUG 0

typedef struct Code {
  char character;
  int length;
  char *code;
} Code;

typedef struct CodeDictionary {
  int codesNr;
  Code *codes;
} CodeDictionary;

typedef struct Header {
  int size; // size of the message in bytes
  MPI_Datatype *type; // message type
  int position; // position in the buffer
} Header;

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int getRand(const int from, const int to)
{
  int num = (rand() % (to - from + 1)) + from;
  return num;
}

void buildCodeDictionaryType(MPI_Datatype *CodeDictType) {
    int blockLengths[] = {1, 1};
  MPI_Datatype types[] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT};
  MPI_Aint offsets[2];

  offsets[0] = offsetof(Code, character);
  offsets[1] = offsetof(Code, length);

  MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockLengths, offsets, types, CodeDictType);
  MPI_Type_commit(CodeDictType);
}

BYTE* buildCodeDictionaryMsg(Header *header, CodeDictionary *dict) {
    header->size = sizeof(int);
    BYTE *buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * (header->size));

    MPI_Pack(&dict->codesNr, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, header->size, &header->position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (DEBUG == 1) {
    printf("\ndict->codesNr = %d\n", dict->codesNr);
    printf("header->size = %d\n", header->size);
    printf("header->position = %d\n\n", header->position);
  }

    for (int i = 0; i < dict->codesNr; i++) {
        header->size += sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + (sizeof(char) * (dict->codes[i].length+1));
        buffer = realloc(buffer, header->size);

        MPI_Pack(&dict->codes[i], 1, *header->type, buffer, header->size, &header->position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (DEBUG == 1) {
      printf("before pack array - header->size = %d\n", header->size);
      printf("before pack array - header->position = %d\n", header->position);
    }

        MPI_Pack(dict->codes[i].code, (dict->codes[i].length+1), MPI_CHAR, buffer, header->size, &header->position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (DEBUG == 1) {
      printf("after pack array - header->size = %d\n", header->size);
      printf("after pack array - header->position = %d\n", header->position);
      printf("\n");
    }
    }

    return buffer;
}

void buildCodeDictionary(Header *header, CodeDictionary *dict, BYTE* buffer) {
    MPI_Unpack(buffer, header->size, &header->position, &dict->codesNr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (DEBUG == 1) {
    printf("dict->codesNr = %d\n", dict->codesNr);
    printf("header->size = %d\n", header->size);
    printf("header->position = %d\n\n", header->position);
  }

  dict->codes = malloc(sizeof(Code) * dict->codesNr);

  // I do it just for the first element because of test
  MPI_Unpack(buffer, header->size, &header->position, &dict->codes[0], 1, *header->type, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (DEBUG == 1) {
    printf("before unpack - header->size = %d\n", header->size);
    printf("before unpack - header->position = %d\n", header->position);
  }
  
  dict->codes[0].code = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dict->codes[0].length+1));
  MPI_Unpack(buffer, header->size, &header->position, &dict->codes[0].code, (dict->codes[0].length+1), MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  
  if (DEBUG == 1) {
    printf("after unpack - header->size = %d\n", header->size);
    printf("after unpack - header->position = %d\n", header->position);
  }

  // just for test
  printf("character: %c\tlength: %d\tcode: ",
    dict->codes[0].character,
    dict->codes[0].length);
  printf("%s\n",  dict->codes[0].code); // it crashes here
  
  // if it works do a for in order to unpack all the data
  // ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  // Create a CodeDictionary variable
  CodeDictionary dict;

  if (world_rank == 0)
    printf("sending\n\n");

  if (world_rank == 0) {
    dict.codesNr = getRand(5, 9);
    dict.codes = malloc(sizeof(Code) * dict.codesNr);

    // create some fake values
    for (int i = 0; i < dict.codesNr; i++) {
      dict.codes[i].character = 'a' + i;
      dict.codes[i].length = getRand(1, 9);
      dict.codes[i].code = malloc(sizeof(char) * (dict.codes[i].length+1));

      for (int j = 0; j < dict.codes[i].length; j++) {
        int randChar = getRand('a', 'z');
        dict.codes[i].code[j] = randChar + j;
      }

      dict.codes[i].code[dict.codes[i].length] = '\0';

      if (DEBUG == 1)
        printf("strlen(dict.charEncoding[%d].encoding): %d\n", i, strlen(dict.codes[i].code));
    }

        printf("source data\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < dict.codesNr; i++) {
      printf("codes[%d]:\n\t", i);

      printf("character: %c\tlength: %d\tcode: ", dict.codes[i].character, dict.codes[i].length);
      for (int j = 0; j < dict.codes[i].length; j++)
        printf("%c", dict.codes[i].code[j]);

            printf("\n");
    }
  }

  MPI_Datatype codeDictType;
  buildCodeDictionaryType(&codeDictType);

  Header header = {.size = 0, .position = 0, .type = NULL};
  header.type = &codeDictType;

  BYTE *buffer = NULL;

  if (world_rank == 0)
    buffer = buildCodeDictionaryMsg(&header, &dict);

  MPI_Bcast(&header.size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (DEBUG == 1)
    printf("rank %d: header.size = %d\n", world_rank, header.size);

  if (world_rank != 0)
    buffer = calloc(header.size, sizeof(BYTE));

  MPI_Bcast(buffer, header.size, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (world_rank != 0) {
    printf("\nreceiving\n\n");
    
    buildCodeDictionary(&header, &dict, buffer);

        // printf("received data\n");
        // for (int i = 0; i < dict.codesNr; i++) {
    //   printf("codes[%d]:\n\t", i);

    //   printf("character: %c\tlength: %d\tcode: ", dict.codes[i].character, dict.codes[i].length);
    //   for (int j = 0; j < dict.codes[i].length; j++)
    //     printf("%c", dict.codes[i].code[j]);

        //  printf("\n");
    // }
  }

  free(buffer);

  MPI_Type_free(&codeDictType);

  for (int i = 0; i < dict.codesNr; i++)
    free(dict.codes[i].code);
  
  free(dict.codes);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

For some reason this line of code doesn't work `MPI_Unpack(buffer, header->size, &header->position, &dict->codes[0].code, (dict->codes[0].length+1), MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` because if I try to print the received array, the run crashes with `segmentation fault` as error.

I don't understand why it happens, I take care of the memory by allocating the right size, \0 character included.

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: you need to unpack into `dict->codes[0].code`

Comment: You're right, that's a stupid error, thanks